# Can you edit a workout?

Tags: apple-watch

I mistakenly selected an outdoor walk instead of an outdoor run in the Workout app for Apple Watch. I realised after my run and wondered if there was a way to edit the type of workout on the iPhone?

Looking back at my workout history, it looks a little ridiculous.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this, myself.